# how to show result based on percentage value in query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query where I calculate the percentage value based on  values in controls on a form and subform

```
=[Total]/[Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![mainTotal]
```

If I put >= 50 in the query criteria it returns a Parameter value input

What I want to do in the query is show the result up to 50%. Please help.

```
SELECT Val([SumTest1])+Val([SumTest2]) AS Total, QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.PatientID, QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.Test1, QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.Test2, [Total]/[Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![mainTotal] AS Expr1
FROM QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2
WHERE ((([Total]/[Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![mainTotal])>=50))
ORDER BY Val([SumTest1])+Val([SumTest2]) DESC;
```

Comment: please  post sample data and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried with putting >=50 in criteria of the query field but it does't work.

Comment: As already requested, edit question to provide sample data and query SQL. What you show looks like an expression from textbox.

Comment: June 7 I have added the query SQL.

Comment: Yes so how can I make the query show result only upto 50% match. If I remove the >=50 value in the criteria it show me all the percentage results

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to "Total" as it's being calculated on the fly.  Use the calculation in your query, rather than the name of the value:

```
SELECT 
    Val([SumTest1])+Val([SumTest2]) AS Total, 
    QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.PatientID, 
    QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.Test1, 
    QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2.Test2,
    [Total]/[Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![mainTotal] AS Expr1
FROM QryDSTResultsGroupbyID2
WHERE (((Val([SumTest1])+Val([SumTest2]) )/[Forms]![FrmDSTResultsCompare]![mainTotal])>=50)
ORDER BY Val([SumTest1])+Val([SumTest2]) DESC;
```

Comment: It is not showing the parameter input box but it is not showing any result.